# How can I convert to a string in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe consisting of the following entries:

```
1 2 a b x a b x n j k 
2 3 g h k k h i o p y
3 4 h g y u i o p n l
.....................
```

I want convert the values in columns from 3 to 11 to a string and store in the original dataframe.

```
1 2 abxabxnjk
2 3 ghkkhiopy
3 4 hgyuiopnl
.............
```

I tried doing it with the help of a for loop by using collapse in paste command, but it is taking like infinite amount of time. How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("
1 2 a b x a b x n j k 
2 3 g h k k h i o p y
3 4 h g y u i o p n l"))

cbind(a[, 1:2], str=apply(a[, 3:ncol(a)], 1, paste0, collapse=""))

##   V1 V2       str
## 1  1  2 abxabxnjk
## 2  2  3 ghkkhiopy
## 3  3  4 hgyuiopnl
```

Comment: Why are you joining the 2 in the string? That is not what I want.

Comment: It was a typo, just changed it.

Comment: @rohansingh, seriously? Complaining about a typo? Couldn't you work with the original answer and identify the solution from what was provided?

Comment: I am new to this forum. Sorry if that is considered bad.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
> df$newcol <- do.call(paste0, df[,3:11])
#> df
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11    newcol
#1  1  2  a  b  x  a  b  x  n   j   k abxabxnjk
#2  2  3  g  h  k  k  h  i  o   p   y ghkkhiopy
#3  3  4  h  g  y  u  i  o  p   n   l hgyuiopnl

> df <- df[, c(1,2,12)]
#> df
#  V1 V2    newcol
#1  1  2 abxabxnjk
#2  2  3 ghkkhiopy
#3  3  4 hgyuiopnl
```